Not able to use azure video indexer action in power automate flow and getting the error saying “user not signed in”
I have created a video indexer resource group in azure and registered app in AAD also given contributed role assignment but still not able to utilise this upload video and index action in power automate flow.

The “Contributor” role should generally be sufficient,
